# Three Cardinality Problems

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition of Cardinality: number of elements in the set

1. A = {1,2,3,{1,2,3},4,{4}}

So, I began solving this

|A| = |{1,2,3,{1,2,3},4,{4}}|

```
= 6
```

2. B = {x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$: |x| = -1}

|B| = |{x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$: |x| = -1}|

no, $\mathbb{R}$ inside of |x| will never equal -1, so the answer is 0? If it is zero, why is it zero?

3. D = {n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$: n < 0}

|D| = |{n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$: n < 0}|

D = 0 because no natural number is less than zero. But why is it zero?

Comment: Both sets $B$ and $D$ are the empty set, whose cardinality (i.e. the number of elements it has) is $0$. In other words, how many natural numbers are less than $0$? Answer: $0$ many.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about the cardinality of empty set. 

is my first question correctly, done?

Comment: yes $|A|=6$ as you wrote.